# загружать текст прям в цикле Js

Tags: javascript, html, циклы

Помогите, столкнулся с проблемой. Я пишу программу для "СкороЧтения", я получаю содержание **textarea**, разбиваю его по словам в массив(через метод **split()**) и через **цикл** с задержкой вывожу каждый элемент массива на экран. И так к проблеме. Текст начинает менятся только после **окончания цикла**. то есть загружается последний элемент массива (последнее слово). а во время работы цикла страница как бы **недоступна** И как бы и вся проблема

```
            
            input_val = String($('.main-input').val());
            
            var arrayOfStrings = input_val.split(' ');         
            
            for (var i in arrayOfStrings){
                
                sleep(200, arrayOfStrings[i]);
            }
                        
        });
        function sleep(milliseconds, x) {
            const date = Date.now();
            let currentDate = null;
            do {
                currentDate = Date.now();
            } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
            
        }
```

Я уже не знаю что делать...( Я понимаю что скорее всего это особенность **Js** но тем не менее

Comment: Пока работает JS код ничего рисоваться не может. делать задержку бесконечным циклом нельзя. Надо использовать функции setInterval или setTimeout https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input_val = "Ваша строка";
let arrayOfStrings = input_val.split(' ');
let x = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  func(x)
}, 2000);

function func() {
  if (x >= arrayOfStrings.length) {
    clearInterval()
  } else {
    console.log(arrayOfStrings[x])
  }
  x = x + 1;
}
console.log("доступ к старнице");
```

Comment: Как вариант решения, прошу не судить строго

Comment: благодарю, я как раз хотел попробывать SetInterval, но вы меня опередили)))

Comment: Супер, рад что получилось помочь, ES6 много удобных и крутых вещей добавил)Успехов вам!